# How to get a reference to the Variable object a ReadVariableOp is reading?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have code of the following form:

```
project_ops = []
for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
  if op.type == 'Conv2D':
    activations, kernel = op.inputs
    batch_size, height, width, num_channels = activations.shape.as_list()
    kernel_size_height, kernel_size_width, input_channels, output_channels = kernel.shape.as_list()
    print(activations.shape.as_list(), kernel.shape.as_list())
    project_ops.append(tf.assign(kernel, Orthoganalize(kernel, [height, width])))
```

This doesn't work since `kernel` is not a Variable but a ReadVariableOp. I was hoping to get the Variable from it, but it doesn't seem to have a reference for the variable accessible in Python?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a neat way, but you can do use the following function:

```
def get_var_from(readOp): # make sure to pass a tf.Operation with
                          # readOp.type == 'ReadVariableOp'
    handleOp = readOp.inputs[0].op
    for var in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES):
        if var.op is handleOp:
            return var
```

This takes the VarHandleOp instance which is unique to one tf.Variable (*) and reads all the Variables to find the one, which uses the Handle. (Note, that the ReadVariableOp is not unique to the variable. That can be used for re-reading the Variable. )

I could not see a link from the handle to the tf.Variable -instance and maybe there is none in the Python API, maybe it's a one-directional link.

(*) to my understanding you use ResourceVariables, so this description may only refer to ResourceVariables.